# jquery is not working on ajax loaded content

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".click").on('click', function(){
        var target = $(this).parent().children(".expand");
        $(target).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

HTML content loaded by AJAX:

```html
<div class="click" >...div with expand ....</div>
<div class="click" >...div with expand ....</div>
```

Can any one correct my code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see any ajax requests?

Comment: Please post your complete code.

Comment: are `<div class="click" >` loaded with ajax or content inside it loads with ajax?

Comment: any error on `console`

Answer (score 1):

`<div class="click"></div>` is dynamically created element so we need to use the **event delegation** here.

Reference: [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Try This,

```
$(document).on('click', '.click', function(){
    // Do something
});
```

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted as this is the correct answer.

Comment: m also confused why I get downvote...dear downvoter pls explain

Comment: Yeah I had a correct answer with -1... People ... Here you're +1 for the record

Comment: Awesome thanks you so much working fine!! if possible can you please explain y

Comment: @user3598375: This is because the event handler needs to be attached to some `DOM`-element that is present when the page loads, here `document` (but could have been `'body'` or else). The second argument provide the very element on which you want to bind the event.